# Close jQuery Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a [Site](http://asashopmedicalplan.org/maplocation.aspx?dest=medical.aspx) that was built with some scripts from [codelifter.com](http://codelifter.com/) it is a very old site and I need to make one little edit. I did not create the site i am just wondering why the JavaScript popup wont close. If you click on CA you get a coming soon but if you click on TX it opens a popup that will not close.

My question is what line of code do i need to change to get that to close?

Is the issue with the below code?

Thanks

```
var strGoToUrl = "";

        function ShowPopup(strUrl) {
            var str = '<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="background:black"><tr>';
            str += '<td style="background:#ffeccc" width="460">';
            str += '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%"><tr>';
            str += '<td align="right"><a href="javascript:HidePopup();">Close</a></td>';
            str += '</tr><tr>';
            str += '<td align="center">';
            str += 'TODAY- ASA members can get medical insurance quotes and buy quality, affordable ';
            str += 'medical insurance group plans through Benefit Consultants Northwest (BCNW).<br/><br/>';
            str += '<a href=\"' + strUrl + '\">Click here for Quotes, Medical plan information and plan selections.</a><br/>';
            str += '<a href=\"' + strUrl + '\"><img src="images/bcnw_logo3.gif" width="186" height="60" border="0" /></a><br/>';
            str += 'Automotive Industry Health Insurance Trust (A-HIT) association medical plans ';
            str += 'are not currently available in this state.<br/><br/>';
            str += '</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>';

            strGoToUrl = strUrl;
            alert(strGoToUrl);

            if (document.getElementById) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("popupDiv");
                elem.innerHTML = str;
                elem.style.display = "block";
                ShowRectangularDynamicDropShadow(elem, "#333333", 5);
            }
        }

        function GoToUrl() {
            alert(strGoToUrl);
            window.location = strGoToUrl;
        }

        function HidePopup() {
            if (document.getElementById) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("popupDiv");
                HideRectangularDynamicDropShadow(elem);
                elem.style.display = "none";
                elem.innerhtml = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: The site works just fine in Firefox.  What browsers are you seeing this behavior in?  In addition, have you done any debugging to see if you're getting errors?  My guess is that you have not.  at line 256 of maploacation.aspx you're getting errors: document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;

Comment: I observed in Chrome. There are a bunch errors you can observe in the console. So, you need to correct those first for the function to execute. (Quick hack)Instead of trying to make the display none, try deleting that  node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Not tested but should work...

```
<div id="popupDiv">

//Rest of the code

<div id="shadow"></div>
</div>

function ShowPopup(strUrl) {
        //rest of the code
          shadowDiv = document.getElementById("shadow").style.display = 'block';
          ShowRectangularDynamicDropShadow(shadowDiv, "#333333", 5);
        //rest of the code
}

   function HidePopup() {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var elem = document.getElementById("popupDiv");
            shadowDiv = document.getElementById("shadow");
            HideRectangularDynamicDropShadow(shadowDiv);
            elem.style.display = "none";
            shadowDiv.style.display = "none";
            elem.innerhtml = "";
        }
    }
```